# pass data to javascript from rails view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am having trouble with passing the correct data from my rails html.erb view file to my js file.

I have the following in my controller (@messages = Message.all) and in my html.erb view file:

```
@messages.each do |x|
x.name
end
```

if i have a javscript file how do i pass the id of the specific message to it?

I am trying this:

```
@messages.each do |x|
<span id="messageid" data-id="<%= x.id %>">
 <%=x.name%>
</span>
end
```

and in my javascript file:

```
$("#messageemail").click(function(){
  var messageid = $("#messageemail").data('id');
alert(messageid);
```

this partially works, but it only gives me the id for the first message in the list. I want it to give me the specific id of which ever message is clicked

Comment: Where is element with `messageemail` id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead, add a `class` to your span element instead of `id`

```
<span class="message-class" data-id="<%= x.id %>">
```

In Javascript file

```
$(".message-class").on('click', function(){
  var messageid = $(this).attr("data-id");
  alert(messageid);
});
```

This will work!

Answer (score -1):

In your rails view:

```
<span  onclick="callJS(<%= x.id %>)">
 <%=x.name%>
</span>
```

Here on clicking the span the callJS function will be called.

in the js :

```
// in your js file
 function callJS(x_id){
  console.log(x_id);
}
```